# What is NVIDA's CUDA '__syncthreads()' equivalent in conventional C++. How to synchronize threads professionally?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, synchronization

There are 4 threads in my application. One is main thread and 3 others are working threads. I want first 2 of these 3 working threads to generate data an 3rd to be writing it while it is being generated. Data generator threads shold be synchronized that they run in parallel (starting every iteration of 'for' loop in the same time). Writer thread should be writing all the time if CPU is fast enough. I don't know how to synchronize all these 3 threads professionally in C++, so I wrote the code like there was '`__syncthreads()`' function to represent what I mean best way I can. Is there an equivalent of CUDA C '`__syncthreads()`' in conventional C++ ? If not then how to implement synchronization optimally the way I want ? (I don't like those `while` loops in the code. They simply make higher CPU utilization unnecessarily)

```
volatile bool write_flag ;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...
    write_flag = false ; // nothing to write at the beginning
    ...
    HANDLE *trdHandles = new HANDLE[WORKING_THREADS] ;
    int IDs[] = {0, 1} ; // IDs for generator threads

    trdHandles[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, generator, &IDs[0], 0, NULL) ;  // 1st data generator thread
    if(trdHandles[0] == NULL)
    ExitProcess(0) ;
    trdHandles[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, generator, &IDs[1], 0, NULL) ;  // 2nd data generator thread
    if(trdHandles[1] == NULL)
    ExitProcess(0) ;

    trdHandles[2] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, writer, f_out, 0, NULL) ;  // writer thread
    if(trdHandles[2] == NULL)
    ExitProcess(0) ;
    ...
}

WINAPI DWORD generator(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    int *ID = static_cast<int*>(lpParam) ;
    dataGen(*ID) ;
    return 0 ;
}

void dataGen(int id)
{
    ...
    for(int aa = 0; aa < cycles; aa++)
    {
        __syncthreads() ;

        ... // both threads generate data here in parallel

        while(write_flag) // don't generate data too fast. Wait for writes to complete (this flag is initially set to 'false')
        ;
        setBuffers(id, aa) ; // for swapping in/out buffers
        if(id == 0) // only one thread needs to set the flag
        write_flag = true ;
     }
}

WINAPI DWORD writer(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    ofstream *f_out = static_cast<ofstream*>(lpParam) ;
    while(1)
    {
        if(write_flag)
        {
            f_out->write(out_buffer0, chunk_len) ;
            f_out->write(out_buffer1, chunk_len) ;
            write_flag = false ;
            if(!finish)
            continue ;
            else
            return 0 ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look for an implementation of the barrier pattern as described in section 3.5 of [The Little Book Of Semaphores](http://spinroot.com/spin/Doc/course/2005_downey_semaphores.pdf).

The barrier pattern is used for syncing up threads just as you describe.

Comment: Thanks for the book. I hope it'll be useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have direct support for multithreading (until C++11). You have to use OS services to implement multithreading and synchronization. On Windows there is a rich set of [Synchronization Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360.aspx). For your scenario look into the [Wait Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360.aspx#wait_functions) and [Event Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360.aspx#event_functions). A combination of [`SetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211.aspx) and [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025.aspx) will be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

The book "The Little Book Of Semaphores" is not so bad, however it is concentrated on programming aspects in general, not just on C++ as I expected. But the book has helped me as I found detailed C++ barrier pattern explanation faster then I could without it. After reading this:

http://adilevin.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/locking-mechanisms/

and this:

http://adilevin.wordpress.com/category/multithreading/ (The barrier main function section)

I had to spend only some little time in order to resolve my problem. I resolved it by using some combination of one `bool` flag, `Semaphore` objects and mainly `WaitForSingleObject()` calls as presented in the code below. I'm sure it works because there are no assertion errors during runtime. It's complete code similar to the code of my application but this one represent only how I solved the problem. If You have any suggestions to this code - if it can be implemented a better way, then please answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

#define THREADS_NUM 3

WINAPI DWORD generator(LPVOID lpParam) ;
WINAPI DWORD writer(LPVOID lpParam) ;
void dataGen(int id) ;
void locker() ;
void sync_msg_display(std::string msg) ;

volatile bool write_flag = false, finish = false ;
volatile long entered_num ;
int time0 = 950, time1 = 1050, time2 = 550 ;

HANDLE sem0, sem1, sem2 ;

using namespace std ;

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE trdHandles[THREADS_NUM] ;
    int IDs[THREADS_NUM] ;

    for(int aa = 0; aa < THREADS_NUM; aa++)
    IDs[aa] = aa ;

    entered_num = 0 ;
    sem0 = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 4096, NULL) ;

    for(int aa = 0; aa < THREADS_NUM - 1; aa++)
    trdHandles[aa] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, generator, &IDs[aa], 0, NULL) ;
    trdHandles[THREADS_NUM - 1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, writer, &IDs[THREADS_NUM - 1], 0, NULL) ;

    for(int aa = 0; aa < THREADS_NUM; aa++)
    if(trdHandles[aa] == NULL)
    ExitProcess(0) ;

    WaitForMultipleObjects(THREADS_NUM, trdHandles, true, INFINITE) ;
    for(int aa = 0; aa < THREADS_NUM; aa++)
    CloseHandle(trdHandles[aa]) ;

    CloseHandle(sem0) ;
    CloseHandle(sem1) ;
    CloseHandle(sem2) ;

    cout << "finished !" << endl ; 

    getch() ;
    return 0 ;
}

WINAPI DWORD generator(LPVOID lpParam)
{
int id = *(static_cast<int*>(lpParam)) ;
dataGen(id) ;
return 0 ;
}

WINAPI DWORD writer(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    LONG prev ;
    sem1 = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 4096, NULL) ;
    sem2 = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 4096, NULL) ;
    while(1)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(sem1, INFINITE) ;
        write_flag = true ;

        sync_msg_display("Write started.") ;
        Sleep(time2) ;
        sync_msg_display("Write finished.") ;

        write_flag = false ;
        ReleaseSemaphore(sem2, 2, &prev) ;
        if(finish)
        return 0 ;
    }
}

void dataGen(int id)
{
    LONG prev ;
    stringstream ss ;
    for(int aa = 0; aa < 20; aa++)
    {
        if(id == 0)
        {
            ss << aa ;
            sync_msg_display("Generator thread no. 0 iteration no. " + ss.str() + " start.") ;
            ss.str("") ;
            if(aa % 2)
            Sleep(time0) ;
            else
            Sleep(time1) ;
            ss << aa ;
            sync_msg_display("Generator thread no. 0 iteration no. " + ss.str() + " complete.") ;
            ss.str("") ;
        }
        else
        {
            ss << aa ;
            sync_msg_display("Generator thread no. 1 iteration no. " + ss.str() + " start.") ;
            ss.str("") ;
            if(aa % 2)
            Sleep(time1) ;
            else
            Sleep(time0) ;
            ss << aa ;
            sync_msg_display("Generator thread no. 1 iteration no. " + ss.str() + " complete.") ;
            ss.str("") ;
        }

        if(write_flag) // don't generate data too fast. Wait for writes to complete (this flag is initially set to 'false')
        WaitForSingleObject(sem2, INFINITE) ;

        assert(!write_flag) ;
        Sleep(10) ; ////
        assert(!write_flag) ;

        locker() ;

        if(id == 0) // only one thread needs to set the flag
        ReleaseSemaphore(sem1, 1, &prev) ;
    }
    locker() ;
    if(id == 0)
    finish = true ;
}

void locker()
{
    LONG prev ;
    if(InterlockedIncrement(&entered_num) < 2)
    WaitForSingleObject(sem0, INFINITE) ;
    else
    {
        entered_num = 0 ;
        ReleaseSemaphore(sem0, 1, &prev) ;
    }
}

void sync_msg_display(string msg)
{
    HANDLE lock = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, "mutex") ;
    WaitForSingleObject(lock, INFINITE) ;
    cout << msg << endl ;
    ReleaseMutex(lock) ;
    CloseHandle(lock) ;
}
```